# GNU C Compiler 4 (gcc) syntax/configuration for Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: gcc, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

While converting all my existing `Jenkins` job to [Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) jobs I got stuck with the step to do `Scan for compiler warnings` in the post build actions as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

I tried lot of syntax for this, but it didn't workout.
Does anyone know the syntax for this in pipeline ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot finally I found the script which works.

```
post {
    always {
            step([$class: 'WarningsPublisher',
            consoleParsers: [[parserName:'GNU C Compiler 4 (gcc)']],
            defaultEncoding: '',
            excludePattern: '',
            healthy: '',
            includePattern: '',
            messagesPattern: '',
            unHealthy: '',
            useStableBuildAsReference: true
        ])
    }
}
```

The above script is tested and it works good.